# Export (save as) jpg using layer name in Photoshop action

Tags: jpeg, photoshop, photoshop-script

is it possible to copy the current active layer name in Photoshop and use it as the file name for a 'Save As' command in a Photoshop action?

Export Layers to Files isn't suitable because I only want to save a single jpg at a particular point in the action, but because the action is recursive I need a way of changing the filename so that the resulting jpg isn't overwritten with each recursion.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to get the name of the `activeLayer` and save it within an variable:

```
var layerName = app.activeDocument.activeLayer.name;
var destFile = new File ("~/Desktop/" + layerName + ".jpg");
```

If you want to `document.saveAs()` you should set the `asCopy` parameter to `true`:

```
app.activeDocument.saveAs (destFile, docExportOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
```

This will prevent a name change of the file you're working with.

Instead of `document.saveAs()` you could use `document.exportDocument()` in case you want a really small JPEG output.

```
app.activeDocument.exportDocument (destFile, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, docExportOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried : `"Export layers to files..."` in `Files`, `Script` ? You don't tell us which method you are using right now.
This should export each layer with their name + a custom prefix of your choice.

Also, you may want to take a look at the `Insert Menu Item` that lets you record a set of actions and then does it automatically. If you need something more complex than the first option, this might be your solution.

Comment: Hi Carele, Export Layers to Files isn't suitable because I only want to save a single jpg at a particular point in the action, not the entire set of layers individually. Insert Menu item also doesn't help with the core problem of copying the layer file name.

Comment: Sorry then, i think you'll have to find someone more pro to give you insights, if it's possible at all...